# How can I delete in cascade?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I create a database with postgresql :

```
elt {
    id : bigserial,
    elt_name : character varying(40),
}

history_elt {
    id : bigserial,
    previous_elt_id : bigint , // (with on update no action and on delete no action)
    reason : character varying(250)
}
```

But I want to have a super administrator user in my application so the user could delete in cascade only if he is a super administrator.

It is possible to do it with entity framework because I do this

```
[HttpDelete("[Action]{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Elt>> DeleteCascade(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var elt = await _context.Elts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
        var historyEltToDelete= _context.HistoryElts.Where(t => t.PreviousEltId == elt .Id);

        _context.Elts.Remove(elt);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        historyEltToDelete.Reason= "Delete of elt"+elt.EltName;



 _context.Entry(historyEltToDelete).CurrentValues.SetValues(historyEltToDelete);
                    _context.SaveChanges();

                return Ok(historyEltToDelete);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);

    }

}
```

When I want to try to delete a elt I have this error message :

> update or delete on table "elt" violates foreign key constraint "previous_elt_id_fkey" on table "history_elt"

How can I resolve my issue ?

Comment: delete the child related objects which have foreign key references to the parent object youre trying to delete before trying to delete the parent. EF does not support setting cascade delete based on roles out of the box, you need to implement it manually

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to delete a Row, which has a primary key, which got refered by a foreign Key from another Row/Table

The Primary Key is in "elt" and the foreign key is "previous_elt_id_fkey" on the Table "history_elt"

So you need to delete the Value from the other Row/Table which referes to this primary key, when the column allows NULL values.
Or you delete the referenceing Row too.

Or you alter your Column to allow Null Values.

Or another idea from me, because i like to handle it so:

add to "elt" a column BIT (boolean) type and add to your query, that it shouldn't handle rows, which have this column set on true.
Example given:

```
SELECT * FROM eft WHERE bitColumn = 'false'
```

Then you dont need to delete the row, you just tag the BIT Column as true

Comment: If you go with the "soft delete" method, I would strongly recommend that you make the column name clearer. Perhaps call it `deleted`, or even better, make it a timestamp column called `deleted_on`, so that you can have a timestamp of when the delete actually occurred. It helps a lot with auditing. `SELECT * FROM eft WHERE deleted_on is null`

Comment: RToyo is right, name the Column, It was meant to do so.
I thought, because you have a History Table, you will save this event there,
So if you don't, then use a DATETIME Column and a VARCHAR Column, to save, who deleted it. It will be necessary if you wan't to refactor an event.